# Slide animation between div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I need your help, I'm facing a problem trying to do a slide animation between the divs on the navbar (these are the links -> *home,collection,blog*).

My request for help includes knowing how can I put a slide effect when I'm clicking on one of the divs in the main menu containing the **a tags** (*links*)

I want the divs to replace each other in a slide animation.

Here's my code snippet:

```js
/* global document */
/*eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "vars": "local" }]*/
function home_function() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("home").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("collection").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("blog").style.display = "none";
}

function collection_function() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("collection").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("blog").style.display = "none";
}

function blog_function() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("collection").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("blog").style.display = "block";
}

function home_op_function() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("home_btn").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("col_btn").style.opacity = "0.5";
  document.getElementById("blog_btn").style.opacity = "0.5";
}

function col_op_function() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("home_btn").style.opacity = "0.5";
  document.getElementById("col_btn").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("blog_btn").style.opacity = "0.5";

}

function blog_op_function() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("home_btn").style.opacity = "0.5";
  document.getElementById("col_btn").style.opacity = "0.5";
  document.getElementById("blog_btn").style.opacity = "1";
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

#head_sec {
  font-family: 'expressway';
  height: 176px;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  overflow: auto;
  color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#head {
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

#lf_stl {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 176px;
  /*
    position: fixed;
    right: 855px;
    top: 68.1px;
*/
  letter-spacing: 2.2px;
}

#srch:visited {}

#hlp {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#slsh {
  float: left;
}

#my_act {
  float: right;
}

#checkout {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 358px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.main_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  font-family: 'expressway';
}

button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}

button#head {
  color: white;
}

.hd_btn {
  color: white;
}

.main_btn {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 110px;
  font-weight: 810;
  color: #2a2a2a;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.main_btn:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#collection {
  display: none;
}

#blog {
  display: none;
}

#col_btn {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#blog_btn {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#home_btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#home_btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  ;
}

#main_pic {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="media.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fonts.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2aa44c19e6.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <section id="head_sec">
    <div id="head">
      <!--
                <button class="hd_btn" id="srch">HOME</button>
                <p class="hd_btn" id="slsh">/</p>
                <button class="hd_btn" id="hlp">HELP</button>
                <button class="hd_btn" id="checkout">CHECKOUT</button>
                <button class="hd_btn" id="my_act">MY ACCOUNT</button>
-->
    </div>
    <p id="lf_stl">LIFE STYLE</p>
  </section>
  <section class="main_menu">
    <div class="main_btn"><a id="home_btn" onclick="home_function(); home_op_function()">HOME</a></div>
    <div class="main_btn"> <a id="col_btn" id onclick="collection_function(); col_op_function()">COLLECTION</a></div>
    <div class="main_btn"> <a id="blog_btn" onclick="blog_function(); blog_op_function()">BLOG</a> </div>
  </section>
  <section id="mid_sec">
    <div id="home">
      <img id="main_pic" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594175157129-8d36c241217c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"> f
    </div>
    <div id="collection">
      y
    </div>
    <div id="blog">
      c
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Early thanking,
Niv

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. From what direction do you want the divs to slide? Should they all slide from the same origin?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, We aren't code writing service so I want will not work there. Please show us your effort.

Comment: @AhmedAli while I totally agree with you, I thought I could guide Niv to the right resources and then suggest he does a little more of that the next time he plans on asking a question.

Comment: @JulianBroudy Hi, i don't really get what you are trying to ask, they are different divs and they should slide one near another and switch each other at the location the div they switched were, thank you for trying to help me, very thankful from you

Comment: I took a look at your code and I must say I see some bad practices, but this is ok as you will learn how things should be done once you see some more examples. As for your current need, I would point you to [animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) to learn how to do these and activate once your button is clicked as a first step if you want to do it on your own. There are many libraries that are built to make this easier for you like [GSAP](https://greensock.com/get-started/) as well as sliders libraries like [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/). Good luck.

Comment: @JulianBroudy thank you so much, ill try what you wrote but i wanted to say thanks from the bottom of my heart

Comment: Don't mention it. Let us know if you need further assistance.

Comment: hi @JulianBroudy, i saw [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209945/jquery-slide-animation-triggered-by-button-click) (dont look at the problem, the slide is what im looking for) so i tried to learn the basics of jquery in w3schools but even tho i learned it in it i still cannot figure out how to put this in my website, if you could help by someway to help me understand this or just send me to some website to learn jquery more well i would be gladful
early thanking,
Niv

Comment: I will take a look as soon as I have some free time on my hands.

Comment: @JulianBroudy late thanking to you, ill hope you'll find some time to help me :)

Comment: Hi Niv, sorry it has taken me so long. Is this still relevant? Should I make you an example?